# Embed google slide (iframe) can I create an button in the web page that controls it?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, google-slides

I have embedded a google slideshow into an HTML page, but now what to control the forward and backwards navigation through the show by using my own created button in my HTML page. Is this possible? What would I look for?